# Append a number retrieved via AJAX (jQuery) to document title, as in Facebook notifications

Tags: jquery, facebook, append, title

I'm wondering how they append the new notification numbers in document title on Facebook
The problem is not to retrieve the numbers (I can easily do it via AJAX), but to append the response to the title. Basically I have this function:

```
function globalCount() {
    var title = $('title').text();
    $('title').load('../ajax/global-title.php', null, function(html){
        $(this).text(title + html)
    }); 
}

globalCount();
var auto_global = setInterval(function() {
    globalCount();
}, 20000);
```

But it doesn't work: on load I have, i.e., "MyTitle (2)", after 20 seconds it becomes "MyTitle (2)(2)", then "MyTitle (2)(2)(2)" and so on. The number retrieved via AJAX is of course dynamic (it could change, based on database queries on "global-title.php").
Please, any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a variable the first time the page loaded as something like:

```
var pagetitle = $('title').text();
```

And then in your code simply write

```
$(this).text(pagetitle + html);
```

This would mean that you would be resetting the title every time and simply appending the newest data.

Comment: Thanks, this works very fine, I didn't thought to set a "global" variable outside the function!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a bit of regex. Assuming your title doesn't have any other brackets, you can do this:

```
function globalCount() {
    var title = $('title').text().replace(/\([0-9]\)/, '');

    $('title').load('../ajax/global-title.php', null, function(html){
        $(this).text(title + html);
    }); 
}
```

The modification to the `var title` line will strip any strings matching stuff like `(2)` (a bracket, any number, and another bracket), and replace it with nothing.

I've made a regex example [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%5C%28%5B0-9%5D%5C%29&input=Hello%20world.%20%28Notifications%29%20%282%29%20%283%29).